# Angles greater than 360 a deeper question

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've found this code in stack exchange from 2012 and I rather like the general gist of the idea, however, it doesn't seem to work the way I would like it to work. I've looked into various spiral codes and nothing is really doing the job this original code does.

My problem with the code is I don't know how to start the spiral. I would, ideally want to choose the spiral starting location, such as (0.5,0), but when I run this code it seems to only ever start at 1. Then it draws a spiral that is quite large, I would like to control that as well. I want more control than this, is there a way to modify this code to do what I want?

I'm running this within the pgfplot environment, if that's important.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows}

 \begin{document} 

 \newcommand\bigangle[2][]{% 
    \draw[->,domain=0:#2,variable=\t,samples=200,>=latex,#1]
      plot ({(\t+#2)*cos(\t)/(#2)},
           {(\t+#2)*sin(\t)/(#2)}) node[right=.5cm] {$#2^\circ$}
        ;}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw [thick] ( 0,0) -- (3,0);
 \draw [thick] ( 0,0) -- (0,3); 
 \draw [red,thick] ( 0,0) -- (400:3); 
 \bigangle[blue,dashed]{400}      
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Update: I'm trying to use this code idea to draw within my unit circles, so I'm trying to put it inside this code:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
        \begin{axis}[
            minor tick num=1,
            ticks=none,
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            ymax=1.5,
            ymin=-1.5,
            xmin=-1.5,
            xmax=1.7
            ]
            \addplot[blue,domain=-1:1, samples=100] {(1 - x^2)^0.5};
            \addplot[blue,domain=-1:1, samples=100] {-(1 - x^2)^0.5};
            \addplot[blue, domain=0:1,]{0}node[below left, black]{$360^{\circ}$};
            \draw [red,thick] ( 0,0) -- (400:1); 
            \bigangle[blue,dashed,]{400}; 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: please check if your code compiles in its present form

Comment: My code definitely compiles in the present form, I'm asking if it can be modified to be more powerful and give me more options.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document} 
    
    \newcommand\bigangle[2][]{% 
        \draw[->,domain=0:#2,variable=\t,samples=200,>=latex,#1]
        plot ({(\t+2*#2)*cos(\t)/(2*#2)},
        {(\t+2*#2)*sin(\t)/(2*#2)}) node[right=.5cm] {$#2^\circ$}
        ;}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [thick] ( 0,0) -- (3,0);
        \draw [thick] ( 0,0) -- (0,3); 
        \draw [red,thick] ( 0,0) -- (400:3); 
        \bigangle[blue,dashed]{400};  
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [thick] ( 0,0) -- (3,0);
        \draw [thick] ( 0,0) -- (0,3); 
        \draw [red,thick] ( 0,0) -- (400:3); 
        \bigangle[blue,dashed]{760};  
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [thick] ( 0,0) -- (3,0);
        \draw [thick] ( 0,0) -- (0,3); 
        \draw [red,thick] ( 0,0) -- (60:3); 
        \bigangle[blue,dashed]{1140}   
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What did you change in the code? I just see that you can make more spirals, but this doesn't seem to have anything where I can change the starting location of the spiral.

Comment: @AdamB Four times 2*#2 in your code in place of #2. That's all. I added two graphs for your's trigonometry notes!

Comment: Awesome, that's working the way I want. I was sort of hoping it might be possible to change it in the \draw function rather than scrolling up to the \newcommand. I'm working in a 10 page document on Trig, so scrolling up to make adjustments is annoying haha. Not sure if you have ideas on that, but so far this is doing what I want :)

Comment: @AdamB I have ideas ,I have, I have. I have published a book on trigonometry (in Italian,...almost 300 page...)