# How to draw the dotted part?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to make the figure, but I can't do the dotted part outside the circle.

[image]

My codes are as follows:

\begin{center}

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]

    \draw[line width=.08cm,red,fill=yellow!15] (0,0)circle [radius=1];

    \draw [line width=.08cm,blue,-Stealth] (-1.5,0)--(1.8,0);

    \draw [line width=.08cm,blue,-Stealth] (0,-1.5)--(0,1.8);

    \node at (1.6,-.2){$\pmb{X}$};

    \node at (.2,1.6){$\pmb{Y}$};

    \node at (.1,-.1){$\pmb{O}$};

    \node at (1.4,.1){$\pmb{A=(1,0)}$};

    \node at (60:1.2){$\pmb{P}$};

    \node[blue] at (60:1){$\bullet$};

    \node[blue] at (0:1){$\bullet$};

    \node[blue] at (0,0){$\bullet$};

    \draw (0,0)--(60:1);

    \draw[line width=.08cm,blue,-Stealth] (1,0)--(0:1cm) arc (0:60:1cm);

    \draw[-Stealth] (.3,0)--(0:.3cm) arc (0:60:.3cm);

    \node at (.4,.2){$\pmb{\frac{\pi}{3}rd}$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
```

Comment: Please don't post just code fragments. Always make a small, but compilable test file including the necessary packages etc.

Comment: What *is* the dotted part? Is it a spiral? Does it need to be a spiral? Can it just be semicircles with increasing radii?

Comment: These answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623371/angles-greater-than-360-a-deeper-question/623374#623374 can help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The spiral can be plotted pretty good by providing points every 10° until 780° (which are 2×360° + 60°). The base radius is 1.1 and for each full revolution the radius gains 0.1.

The arrow is specified with a `sep = 2pt` where 2pt is the radius of the dot we will place at the same point.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, quotes}
\tikzset{label quotes in math-mode/.style={every label quotes/.append style={execute at begin node=$, execute at end node=$}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >=Stealth, thick,
  dot/.style={shape=circle, inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt, minimum size=+4pt, fill},
  label quotes in math-mode, x=2.5cm, y=2.5cm]
\path[at end, ->, below left]
  (left:1.5) edge node {$x$} (right:1.5)
  (down:1.5) edge node {$y$} (   up:1.5);

\draw (0,0) circle[radius=1];

\node[dot, "O"         below left] (O)          {};
\node[dot, "{A=(1,0)}" below left] (A) at (1,0) {};

\draw[draw=red, dashed, -{>[sep=+2pt]}] % sep is half the size of dot
  plot[samples at={0,10,...,780}, smooth] (\x:1.1+\x/360*.1)
  node[dot, "P" above](P) {};
\draw (O) -- (P);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]